# How do I use xargs with input containing spaces?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a file containing list of newline separated redis keys (containing spaces). For example:

```
My key 1
My key 2
some other key
```

How do I use xargs to delete them all from redis.

I want to do something like:

`cat file-with-keys | xargs -n1 redis-cli del`

But it doesn't work because of the spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is newline-separated, use:

```
$ cat file_with_keys | xargs -d'\n' printf "<%s>\n"
<My key 1>
<My key 2>
<some other key>
```

The above illustrates the use of `xargs` in a pipeline.  If the source is truly a file, then `cat` is not needed:

```
xargs -d'\n' printf "<%s>\n" <file_with_keys
```

As an aside, one often wants to provide `xargs` with the `-r` or `--no-run-if-empty` option to prevent the program from running if no arguments are supplied:

```
xargs -rd'\n' printf "<%s>\n" <file_with_keys
```

The above assumes GNU `xargs`.  As Jonathan Leffler points out in the comments, other `xargs` may not support these options.  In particular, the [`xargs` on Mac OSX](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) supports neither `-d` nor `-r`.

Comment: Both the `-r` and `-d` options are extensions in GNU `xargs` compared with POSIX [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) — useful extensions, but some caution required, especially on BSD-based systems such as Mac OS X, or non-Linux systems such as HP-UX, AIX, Solaris.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for that.  Answer updated with a compatibility warning.